# Saving 'this' address into a variable

Tags: c++

Will this save the address of what this is pointing to:

```
size_t this_address = size_t(this);
```

Is this portable? I need to save the address of what this is pointing to. Any suggestion on if there is a correct way to go about this. Note, for optimization purposes.

Comment: This looks meaningless without more context, and it's also definitely wrong. Why did you think of `size_t` and not a `void*`?

Comment: `void *that = this;` would be closer to what you want.  Your code just stores how big a pointer is.

Comment: How does this optimize anything?

Comment: @ebyrob: No: to store how *big* a pointer is, you'd write `sizeof(this)`. `size_t(this)` is a cast, and no actual size is computed.

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned integral type that is *at least* as large as a pointer, so this is portable but probably wrong.

Comment: @ruakh thanks.  Did he write size_t?  I totally read it as sizeof().

Comment: are void* comparable?

Comment: @cdhowie No, it's an unsigned integral type that is at least large enough to hold the size of the largest object. In some memory models, that's not the size of a pointer. More importantly, it's *conceptually* quite different. You're thinking of `uintptr_t`.

Comment: @supersam654 made the interesting question... *what do you intend on optimizing here?* This is the [classic XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @delnan Probably. In my experience `size_t` is usually pointer-sized (and I have some evidence that it is on *most* systems) but you are correct. So I retract my statement that it is portable.

Comment: I can't think of many times when I've needed to do this, OTHER than when I'm using some C-style interface that doesn't understand C++ types. Or I'm storing a pointer to a derived object into a container class storing the base-class, of course.

Answer (score 6):

`void *` is a more portable and, in my opinion, more correct way to store a pointer address:

```
void *this_address = this;
```

This said, why do you need this to be portable? It is not type-safe at all, you should use a pointer to the correct (base)-type or, when applicable, a smart pointer of the (base)-type.

Comment: Why did you change it to a `static_cast`?

Comment: Was not sure of implicit cast

Comment: [conv.ptr]/2 "A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv* `T`,” where `T` is an object type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer
to *cv* `void`”." ([conv] are standard conversions, which are implicit conversions)

Comment: If you think you need a cast, but you're not sure, step back. The safe conversions don't need a cast, while the unsafe conversions need both a cast and an understanding. This is by design.

Comment: And my opinion was confirmed when cmaster posted the even simpler solution without any cast.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply say:

```
MyClass* foo = this;
```

No need to do any casting at all.

Comment: +1:  Indeed, there is no evidence that any mucking about with a `void*` is needed here at all.

Answer (score 4):

I think following should be the approach to store the address

`const void* address = static_cast<const void*>(this);`

Comment: I see thanks. I think this was XY problem as David mentioned in the comment. I will think about it more. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Why is everybody suggesting some sort of a cast? There is absolutely no need for it.

Comment: A `static_cast` is not required, an implicit cast is available.

Comment: @cmaster:  I would use an explicit cast here even though it is not needed simply to be, well... explicit.  It makes my intention clear to others.  "Yes, I really do want to cast this to a void*."

Comment: @JohnDibling That was not my point. My point is: Why use a `void*`? I fail to see any need to go away from the known type of the class. A `MyClass*` will do anything you might want to do with this address.

Comment: @cmaster:  Oh, yes.  I see now.  Totally agree, that's why I said that this was the right way to do the *wrong thing*.

Answer (score 1):

If you need some automatic memory management (ownership management and reference counting, for example) you could use `shared_ptr<MyClass>` to store pointer to the object, where `MyClass` is type of the class.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the question is about automatic memory management?  `shared_ptr<>` implements reference counting, and it's not clear at all that this is what the question is about.

Comment: Good idea to use any kind of smart pointer for this, but there might be other options, depending on the type of relation to the reference (e.g. `std::weak_ptr` or similar)!

Comment: Thanks, I will clarify this in my answer.

Comment: @g-makulik It's not possible to know whether this is a good idea without knowing how `this` was allocated and how its lifetime is currently managed.  If `this` refers to a statically-allocated or stack-allocated object then its most certainly **not** a "good idea" to use a smart pointer.

Comment: But, if `this` refers to stack-allocated object, I don't think it is a good idea to store `this` value anywhere, right?

Comment: @cdhowie _' If this refers to a statically-allocated or stack-allocated object'_ Yes of course! This won't be a good idea to wrap stack allocated objects, but statically allocated objects could be wrapped using `std::unique_ptr` safely, can't they?

Comment: @g-makulik No. `unique_ptr` will perform deletion upon destruction. (You can use a custom, no-op deleter but if the object is allocated statically then there is *no benefit* to using smart pointers, since the entire purpose of smart pointers is to manage object lifetime.  Static objects have static lifetime and are effectively managed by the compiler.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric Correct. There are some cases where you might pass such a pointer around, but the value should not be stored long-term unless one is certain that the object will still exist when the pointer is retrieved later.  (For example, storing a pointer to a stack-allocated object declared in `main()` is safe, so long as one does not use it from code that is executed when the application is terminating, for example from destructors of statically-allocated objects.)